# How I can remove composer dev dependencies when I build my application for production using docker multi-stage build?

Tags: php, docker, dependencies, composer-php

I am building my php application into a Docker image using multistage builds as a CI/CD pipeline:

```
FROM etable/php7.2-dev as build

COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN composer install --dev
RUN echo "Run unit tests" && ./vendor/bin/phpunit
RUN echo "Remove unit tests" && rm -rf /var/www/html/tests
RUN echo "Remove webpack" && rm -rf webpack.mix.js

FROM etable/php7.2

RUN mkdir /usr/share/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/share/myapp
COPY --from=build /var/www/html/ .

RUN chown www-data:www-data /usr/share/myapp \
    && find /usr/share/myapp -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \
    && find /path/to/laravel -type d -exec chmod 755 {}

WORKDIR /var/www/html
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

But on stage build I am installing dev dependencies in order to run my unit tests. That because on `composer.json` the phphunit is defined as dev dependency:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

(I am using a default laravel as an example and test for multi-stage builds, but this applies to any php project that uses composer and has phpunit as dev dependency.)

But I have this issue. After I run my php unit tests I do not need the composer dev dependencies any more hence I need them to remove them before I proceed into the next stage because I already have my dependencies installed hence re-downloading them will make the build process slower.

So how I can remove the dev dependencies using composer and keep the production-use ones?

Comment: composer install --no-dev iirc...

Answer (score 2):

Since no one has answered this I will provide a more robust explanation.  First, a little clarification on terminology.  You should not be *removing* dev dependencies from your composer project, you should be deploying it without these dependencies in the first place.  You can accomplish this by committing your composer.lock file and deploying the commit (or preferably tag) with `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`.  This will produce a vendors folder with all of the locked package versions (from composer.lock) without the dev dependencies.  Just in case there is any confusion, you should not be committing your vendors folder to VCS.

Comment: So the command `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` where in mt `Dockerfile` do you suggest that is the best to be placed?

Comment: Also once I have run `composer install --dev` would I exclude the non-dev composer dependencies via the `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` without the need to change a stage?

Comment: I don't have a huge amount of experience with docker, but you should probably have something to the effect of `composer install $(printenv COMPOSER_FLAGS)` and then create the container with COMPOSER_FLAGS="--no-dev --optimize-autoloader" for production.